# How to build a numpy array with np.nan as the first item

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nan

So I'm trying to find out if there is a way to do this similar to having a for loop inside of the np.array. A simple example is set is below.

Normal method:

```
>>> np.array([
... (x, x + 2)
... for x in range(10)
... if x%2 == 0])
array([[ 0,  2],
       [ 2,  4],
       [ 4,  6],
       [ 6,  8],
       [ 8, 10]])
```

The output that I would like to achieve would be:

```
array([[np.nan, np.nan],
       [ 0,  2],
       [ 2,  4],
       [ 4,  6],
       [ 6,  8],
       [ 8, 10]])
```

What I have tried with no success is:

```
>>> np.array([
... (np.nan, np.nan),
... (x, x+2)
... for x in range(10)
... if x%2 == 0])
```

As well as:

```
>>> np.array(
... [np.nan, np.nan],
... [(x, x+2)
... for x in range(10)
... if x%2 == 0])
```

I would like to do this without concatenation of hstack.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update** to match the updated Q.

```
>>> np.array([[np.nan, np.nan], *[(x, x+2) for x in range(10) if x%2 ==0]])
array([[nan, nan],
       [ 0.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  4.],
       [ 4.,  6.],
       [ 6.,  8.],
       [ 8., 10.]])
```

Update ends.

I think what you are trying to do is

```
np.array([[np.nan, np.nan], *5*[[1, 2]]])
```

You could also do the repeating numpy-side

```
np.repeat([[np.nan,np.nan],[1,2]], [1,5], axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `*` to unpack the inner list is the key:

```
In [394]: np.array([[100,101],*[[1,2] for _ in range(3)]])
Out[394]: 
array([[100, 101],
       [  1,   2],
       [  1,   2],
       [  1,   2]])
```

Compare these 2 lists:

```
In [395]: [[100,101],*[[1,2] for _ in range(3)]]
Out[395]: [[100, 101], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]
In [396]: [[100,101],[[1,2] for _ in range(3)]]
Out[396]: [[100, 101], [[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]]
```

If you get the nesting of the lists in input correct, then `np.array` will give you the correct array.

Without the unpacking, the 2nd level lists have different sizes, and you get a object array:

```
In [398]: np.array([[100,101],[[1,2] for _ in range(3)]])
Out[398]: array([list([100, 101]), list([[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]])], dtype=object)
```

`concatenate` (`vstack`) can join those two sublists into the desire array:

```
In [400]: np.vstack(_)
Out[400]: 
array([[100, 101],
       [  1,   2],
       [  1,   2],
       [  1,   2]])
```

I don't think there's anything wrong with the `vstack` method.  It may be easier to understand, especially if you don't use `*alist` very often.

Comment: Does unpacking have any significant change to the speed to create an array? The arrays I'm working with in this case don't normally exceed 3000.

Comment: Also this works perfectly in my main code. Thank you!